# Change HTML Post parameter on Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

I have 1 form, with 2 Submit buttons.

When I click one button, I want certain values to be posted. When I click other button I want other values to be posted.

This is what I tried, did not work:

```
<form action="/test" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" id="bool" name="bool" value="" />

    <input type="submit" value="Yes" onclick="test()" />
    <input type="submit" value="No" onclick="test1()" />

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        document.getElementById('bool').value = "true";
    }
    function test1() {
        document.getElementById('bool').value = "false";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "did not work"? The form didn't submit? The form did submit but 'bool' didn't contain what you thought it should?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<form action="/test" method="post" name="myform">

    <input type="hidden" id="bool" name="bool" value="" />

    <input type="button" value="Yes" onclick="test()" />
    <input type="button" value="No" onclick="test1()" />

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        document.getElementById('bool').value = "true";
        document.myform.submit();
    }
    function test1() {
        document.getElementById('bool').value = "false";
        document.myform.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead:

```
<form action="/test" method="post" onsubmit="document.getElementById('bool').value = 'true'; return true;">

    <input type="hidden" id="bool" name="bool" value="" />

    <input type="submit" value="Yes" onclick="test()" />
    <input type="submit" value="No" onclick="test1()" />

</form>
```

Comment: so when submitting, you always set it to true?

Comment: You're not taking into account that the OP wants a different value on post-back

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem. This wont work! I saw only the true part! Will need to handle the button clicks and submit the form via form.submit() then..