# HTML post specific value on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I have a search bar and I'm trying to intercept the POST, append "tag:", and then submit it so if someone types "apple" in the search bar it comes out tag:apple

```
<form method="get" action="/search" id="search-home">
            <button type="submit" value="search"></button>
            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="product" />
            <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" />
        </form>
```

Comment: You can do it where you will be using `apple`

Comment: Can you try with jQuery?

Comment: What will you with this value?

Comment: I'm confused.  I tried the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450307/change-html-post-parameter-on-submit  
and couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
        <meta name="Author" content="">
        <meta name="Keywords" content="">
        <meta name="Description" content="">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>

            <form method="get" action="/search" id="search-home">
                <button type="submit" value="search">submit</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="product" />
                <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" class="searchtext"/>
            </form>

        <script>
        $(document).on('submit','#search-home',function(){
        var searchtext = $('.searchtext').val();
        $('.searchtext').val("tag:"+searchtext);
        });
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```